# Jibx root package name

Tags: java, maven, jibx

I see that JibX uses a default binding.xml and it contains a package attribute in  tag. Is there a way to override this value? Specifically, can we customize this in jibx-maven-plugin?

Thanks,
Gopal

Answer (score 1):

Gopal,
Absolutely! You can name the binding file anything you like. Just set the <includeSchemaBindings> tag to any binding file name that you are using. For the full customization list, take a look at the documentation here:
[Here: http://jibx.sourceforge.net/maven-jibx-plugin/index.html](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/maven-jibx-plugin/index.html).
Don

Comment: @Don..can we control root package with this? I mean if I have two schemas http://www.xyz123.com/schemas/test/abc.xsd and http://www.xyz123.com/schemas2/test/abc.xsd, by default the packages are generated like com.xyz123.schemas.test and com.xyz123.schemas2.test. While I want jibx to respect schemas.test and schemas2.test, i just want to change the root of the package to custom.xyz. Is this possible to configure in binding.xml? Can you post a sample code if you can? Thanks.

Comment: Gopal.. You can make the package names anything you like. Look at the jibx-plugin params at: http://jibx.sourceforge.net/maven-jibx-plugin/schema-codegen-mojo.html and set the defaultPackage param. Don